# PhpBrowser requires installing of guzzlehttp/guzzle

Tags: codeception

I have just installed via composer codeception and according to this tutorial http://codeception.com/quickstart I have created a first test. Then, I runned it and I got:

```
[Codeception\Exception\ModuleException]
PhpBrowser: Guzzle is not installed. Please install `guzzlehttp/guzzle` with composer
```

But I am really confused because in my composer I have "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~3.8" which I am using in my existing project.

Could you please tell me what to do?

Thank you

Petr

**Solution:**
I have found the problem. I used an old version of guzzle (< 4.0).

Comment: Make sure you are setting up your autoloading correctly --  it is possible the code is downloaded but not being included.

Comment: I have found the problem. I used an old version of guzzle (< 4.0). Thank you.